# Unable to run google app engine script with PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

So, I'm trying to run the Hello World script but whenever I run `dev_appserver.py` I hit a wall.

Here's the error log from the script:

> $ appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/local/bin/php-cgi HelloWorld
>
> ...
>
> ERROR    2016-03-29 12:57:30,588 php_runtime.py:348] The PHP runtime
>   is not available Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users//desktop/appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py",
>   line 344, in new_instance
>       self._check_binaries(php_executable_path, gae_extension_path)   File
>   "/Users//desktop/appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py",
>   line 284, in _check_binaries
>       cls._check_environment(php_executable_path, env)   File "/Users//desktop/appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py",
>   line 259, in _check_environment
>       raise _PHPEnvironmentError(check_process_stdout)
>   _PHPEnvironmentError: No input file specified.

As a background to my El Capitan setup...

I've previously updated PHP to 5.5 using:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5
```

But I've also downloaded via HomeBrew php54 and that's what should be running the php-cgi script I've posted in the executable path above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the php runtime is available in your path?
What happens if you call the runtime from your commandline?

Answer (score 2):

So turns out, the answer was pretty obvious - I'd installed the Go SDK rather than the PHP one! Google's website scrolls to the wrong place when you click PHP. Many hours wasted trying to fix this one - never mind. Hope this helps another as simple as me!

Answer (score 0):

if you already installed google-cloud-sdk run this command :

gcloud components install app-engine-php-darwin

you won't need to specify that path after this